# How to share internet connection from vmware OSX guest to Windows host?

Tags: networking, macos, windows-8.1, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-workstation

I am using `Windows 8.1` through a boot camp partition on an Apple PC and I have installed VMware Workstation.  I have `OS X Snow Leopard` as guest OS within the working Virtual Machine.

I am using a cheap netsetter which has a driver that is only available for OS X.  How can I share my netsetter connection to my host `Windows 8.1` from my vmware guest OS 'Snow Leopard`  so I can update the software contained within the host OS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about running OS X in a virtual machine on non-Apple hosts, which is against the EULA and not supported.

Comment: Hey slhck..,sir I'm really sorry for not mentioning that I'm using apple pc itself.I had installed windows 8.1 along mac and I want to share the internet connection which is only available in mac os with windows os by using vmware.SO my question is not probably off-topic and also not against the EULA.I need this urgently because I need to update my antivirus to get rid all malwares.Please help me sir..

Comment: So are you running Windows through Boot Camp? Which Mac are you using?

Comment: How do you have malware on a virtual machine that doesn't have an internet connection.

Comment: @slhck..Yes,I am running windows through boot camp.I'm using MacBook Pro 6.1 with snow leopard.

Comment: @Ramhound ...I think my computer is infected through external hard drive of my cousin whose pc had an internet connection.Thanks for your quick reply..

Comment: @Grigin - If you are running Windows through a boot camp partition then you should indicate that in the question.  I attempted to do my best to clarify the question for you but you made no mention of that until now ( and it does matter ).

Comment: Thanks Ramhound for clarifying the question for me ..sorry,I'm little week in english.

Comment: @slhck and Ramhound..could you please give me the solution for my above question?

Answer (score 0):

Vmware workstation allow you to have Internet connection on your Guest machine with  bridge connection.

https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html